# FT8 callsign/maidenhead compression encoding

Tags: software, callsign, math, ft8, encoding

I have set myself a challenge to write a Matlab script as proof of concept to send an FT8 CQ call (not necessarily for live transmissions yet, but I may extend the project). So far I have:

- Generated and appended 14-bit CRC to precomputed message bits (from ft8code.exe utility in WSJT-X)
- Generated and appended 83-bit LDPC parity bits to give 174-bit channel symbols
- Implemented tone synthesis and audio-carrier modulation in Matlab for 8 FSK channel symbols

What I am missing is that I'd like to generate the message bits myself in Matlab from the callsign/grid locator. I understand that the callsign is converted to 2*28=56 bit field, locator is converted to a 15 bit field, and there are 6 message type bits giving 77 bits.

My question therefore is

- How do I convert the callsign to a 56-bit binary value and the locator to 15 bits?
- Does it use an ASCII table? Presumably it uses a 0-9, A-Z, space character set.
- What kind of compression is used to squeeze 4-character locator into 15 bits etc? I know the last 6 bits for CQ messages as these do not change so that's one piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the code in [packjt77.f90](https://github.com/pavel-demin/ft8d/blob/master/packjt77.f90). Callsign encoding (for "standard" callsigns that don't require hashing) is in function `pack28`. A quick summary:

1. Adjust a few strange prefixes that don't follow the usual arrangement of letters and numbers. Swaziland `3DA0*` will be encoded as if it was `3D0*` instead, and Guinea `3XA1A` will be encoded as if it was `QA1A` instead. This adjustment is reversed in the decoder, which is possible because it maps to unused parts of the callsign space.
2. "Align" the callsign into a 6-character field by identifying the last (or only) digit, and placing it in the third position. If there are fewer than two characters before the digit, or fewer than three characters after the digit, pad with spaces. If there are more than two characters before, or more than three characters after, this is a "nonstandard" callsign and has to be encoded by hashing. Example: my callsign KC2G becomes `"KC2G  "`, N2XYZ becomes `" N2XYZ"`, and 4U1ITU stays `"4U1ITU"`.
3. Map the first character to its position (zero-indexed) in the list
   `" 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` (37 possibilities), the second to its position in the list `"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` (36), the third to its position in the list `"0123456789"` (10), and the fourth through sixth to their positions in the list
   `" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` (27). Example: `" K1BC "` becomes `(0, 20, 1, 2, 3, 0)`
4. Read this off as a variable-base-(37, 36, 10, 27, 27, 27) integer, e.g.
   ((((0*36 + 20)*10 + 1)*27 + 2)*27 + 3)*27 + 0 = 3957822, or equivalently
   36*10*27*27*27*0 + 10*27*27*27*20 + 27*27*27*1 + 27*27*2 + 27*3 + 0 = 3957822.
5. Add 6257896. The first 2,063,592 codes are used by CQ/QRZ calls, and the next 4,194,304 are used by 22-bit hashed callsigns; regular callsigns start after that. 3957822 + 6257896 = 10215718.
6. Encode the number as 28-bit binary, big-endian; 10215718 = 0000100110111110000100100110.

For grid squares, the encoding is similar except there's no alignment necessary, and it's a base-(18,18,10,10) integer, so FN20 becomes (5, 13, 2, 0), which becomes the integer 5*18*10*10 + 13*10*10 + 2*10 + 0 = 10320. This is then packed into 15 bits. Note that the "RR73" message is actually encoded as a callsign pair plus the grid RR73 (which is valid, but in an uninhabited bit of arctic ocean north of Siberia), and that reception reports are encoded as the values above RR99 (32480).

Comment: Msny Thanks for this comprehensive answer.  It has helped me a lot and contains everything I need to continue my project.

Comment: I've  been wanting to dig into the JS8 Cplus source to try my hand at creating an ascii only interface suitable for a small LCD display. Would anyone here be interested in that ? I'd  love to have a mobile Pi based digital setup without the  need for Qt, laptop, notepad etc. I'm not an expert C++ programmer and would need some help.

Answer (score 1):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   FT8 Transmit Code        %
%      Reference credit to Dr. Jonathon Y. Cheah (NZ0C)          %
%                   for the use of dome of this code                     %
%           Output is audioband cp 4fsk  FT8 message which can be fed to RF carrier modulation hardware or software            %
%               for transmission over the air                                                 %
%                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
close all
clear all
clc
%%
% user entries         ================== % call must have 6 letter 
                        call='BC1DE '     % spaces for standard HAM
                         loc='JO01'        % Radio callsign.
%                      ==================
%
% process various callsign types  
if (chr_normf(call(3))>9)%right shift call sign
        call(6)=call(5);
        call(5)=call(4);
        call(4)=call(3);
        call(3)=call(2);
        call(2)=call(1);
        call(1)=' ';
end
%
calldec=zeros(size(call));
locdec=zeros(size(loc));
chrset=' 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
pad28=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0];
calltype=[0 0 0 0 0 1]; %initialize calltype
%%
for(i=1:37)
    if(chrset(i)==call(1))
    calldec(1)=i-1;
    end
end
chrset='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
for(i=1:36)
    if(chrset(i)==call(2))
    calldec(2)=i-1;
    end
end
chrset='0123456789';
for(i=1:10)
    if(chrset(i)==call(3))
    calldec(3)=i-1;
    end
end
chrset=' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
for(ii=4:6)
for(i=1:27)
    if(chrset(i)==call(ii))
    calldec(ii)=i-1;
    end
end
end
%%
varbase=[37 36 10 27 27 27];
decint=calldec(1)*36*10*27*27*27 + 10*27*27*27*calldec(2) + 27*27*27*calldec(3) + 27*27*calldec(4) + 27*calldec(5) + calldec(6);
decint=decint+6257896;
calltype(1)=mod(decint,2);
%%
chrset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR';
for(ii=1:2)
for(i=1:18)
    if(chrset(i)==loc(ii))
    locdec(ii)=i-1;
    end
end
end
chrset='0123456789';
for(ii=3:4)
for(i=1:10)
    if(chrset(i)==loc(ii))
    locdec(ii)=i-1;
    end
end
end
locbase=[18 18 10 10];
locint=18*10*10*locdec(1)+10*10*locdec(2)+10*locdec(3)+locdec(4);
%%
binint=de2bi(decint,'left-msb',28);
binint=[0 binint(1:end-1)];%rotate right once not sure why but appears necessary
%while(size(binint)<28)  %zero pad for 28 bits
%binint=[ 0 binint];
%end
%while(binint(end)==0)
   % binint=[ 0 binint(1:end-1)];
%end
locbin=de2bi(locint);
while(size(locbin)<15)
locbin=[0 locbin ];
end
locbin=fliplr(locbin);
%%
chrset='0123456789'
%for(u=1:10)
   % if(loc(4)==chrset(u))
      %  loc3=de2bi(u-1,4,'left-msb')
        %break
    %end
%end
%calltype(1:3)=loc3(2:4);
%locbin(end)=loc3(1);
MB=[ pad28 binint calltype(1:3)  locbin calltype(4:end)];
%%
MB=[MB 0 0 0 0 0]
%CSMOD=[CS(8:36) CS(43:72)]
crc14poly =[ 1,   1, 0,   0, 1, 1, 1,   0, 1, 0, 1,   0, 1, 1, 1 ]
%crc14poly =fliplr(crc14poly);
%crc14poly=fliplr(crc14poly);
%'z^14 + z^13 + z ^10+ z^9+z^8+z^6+z^4+z^2+z+1'
ft8_crc= comm.CRCGenerator('Polynomial',[1,   1, 0,   0, 1, 1, 1,   0, 1, 0, 1,   0, 1, 1, 1 ])
MB=MB';
CRC=ft8_crc(MB);
CRC=CRC';
CRC=[CRC(1:77) CRC(83:end)];
%%
% LDPC generator matrix from WSJT-X's ldpc_174_91_c_generator.f90.
% 83 rows, since LDPC(174,91) needs 83 parity bits.
% each row has 23 hex digits, to be turned into 91 bits,
% to be xor'd with the 91 data bits.
%
rawg = [
 hexToBinaryVector( "8329ce11bf31eaf509f27fc",92),
  hexToBinaryVector("761c264e25c259335493132",92),
  hexToBinaryVector("dc265902fb277c6410a1bdc",92), 
 hexToBinaryVector("1b3f417858cd2dd33ec7f62",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("09fda4fee04195fd034783a",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("077cccc11b8873ed5c3d48a",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("29b62afe3ca036f4fe1a9da",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("6054faf5f35d96d3b0c8c3e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("e20798e4310eed27884ae90",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("775c9c08e80e26ddae56318",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("b0b811028c2bf997213487c",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("18a0c9231fc60adf5c5ea32",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("76471e8302a0721e01b12b8",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("ffbccb80ca8341fafb47b2e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("66a72a158f9325a2bf67170",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("c4243689fe85b1c51363a18",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("0dff739414d1a1b34b1c270",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("15b48830636c8b99894972e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("29a89c0d3de81d665489b0e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("4f126f37fa51cbe61bd6b94",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("99c47239d0d97d3c84e0940",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("1919b75119765621bb4f1e8",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("09db12d731faee0b86df6b8",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("488fc33df43fbdeea4eafb4",92),
  hexToBinaryVector("827423ee40b675f756eb5fe",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("abe197c484cb74757144a9a",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("2b500e4bc0ec5a6d2bdbdd0",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("c474aa53d70218761669360",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("8eba1a13db3390bd6718cec",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("753844673a27782cc42012e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("06ff83a145c37035a5c1268",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("3b37417858cc2dd33ec3f62",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("9a4a5a28ee17ca9c324842c",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("bc29f465309c977e89610a4",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("2663ae6ddf8b5ce2bb29488",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("46f231efe457034c1814418",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("3fb2ce85abe9b0c72e06fbe",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("de87481f282c153971a0a2e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("fcd7ccf23c69fa99bba1412",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("f0261447e9490ca8e474cec",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("4410115818196f95cdd7012",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("088fc31df4bfbde2a4eafb4",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("b8fef1b6307729fb0a078c0",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("5afea7acccb77bbc9d99a90",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("49a7016ac653f65ecdc9076",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("1944d085be4e7da8d6cc7d0",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("251f62adc4032f0ee714002",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("56471f8702a0721e00b12b8",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("2b8e4923f2dd51e2d537fa0",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("6b550a40a66f4755de95c26",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("a18ad28d4e27fe92a4f6c84",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("10c2e586388cb82a3d80758",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("ef34a41817ee02133db2eb0",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("7e9c0c54325a9c15836e000",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("3693e572d1fde4cdf079e86",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("bfb2cec5abe1b0c72e07fbe",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("7ee18230c583cccc57d4b08",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("a066cb2fedafc9f52664126",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("bb23725abc47cc5f4cc4cd2",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("ded9dba3bee40c59b5609b4",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("d9a7016ac653e6decdc9036",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("9ad46aed5f707f280ab5fc4",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("e5921c77822587316d7d3c2",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("4f14da8242a8b86dca73352",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("8b8b507ad467d4441df770e",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("22831c9cf1169467ad04b68",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("213b838fe2ae54c38ee7180",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("5d926b6dd71f085181a4e12",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("66ab79d4b29ee6e69509e56",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("958148682d748a38dd68baa",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("b8ce020cf069c32a723ab14",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("f4331d6d461607e95752746",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("6da23ba424b9596133cf9c8",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("a636bcbc7b30c5fbeae67fe",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("5cb0d86a07df654a9089a20",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("f11f106848780fc9ecdd80a",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("1fbb5364fb8d2c9d730d5ba",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("fcb86bc70a50c9d02a5d034",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("a534433029eac15f322e34c",92), 
 hexToBinaryVector("c989d9c7c3d3b8c55d75130",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("7bb38b2f0186d46643ae962",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("2644ebadeb44b9467d1f42c",92), 
  hexToBinaryVector("608cc857594bfbb55d69600",92)
];
%%
%rawg=hex2dec(rawg);
%rawg=de2bi(rawg,'left-msb');
%rawg=fliplr(rawg);
%for(j=1:83)
%rawg(j,:)=hexToBinaryVector(rawg(j,:),'left-msb');
%end
rawg=rawg(:,1:end-1);
CRCMAT=zeros(size(rawg));
%CRC=CRC';
%col_mask=[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
iii=0;
for(i=1:83)
    CRCMAT(i,:)=CRC(:,:);
end
%OUT=bitand(rawg,CRCMAT);
%OUT=xor(rawg,CRCMAT);
OUT=rawg.*CRCMAT;
%%
out=zeros(1,83);
SUM=zeros(1,83);
%temp=[];
for(j=1:83)
SUM(1,j)=sum(OUT(j,:));
%%
out(1,j)=mod(SUM(1,j),2);
end
%%
%if(j==1)
   % out(1,j)=mod(SUM(1,j),2);  %check if we need to set a parity bit
%else
   % out(1,j)=xor(out(1,j-1),mod(SUM(1,j),2));
%end
    %if(out(1,j)==1)
    %out=out|col_mask
    %out=or(out,col_mask)
    %end
   % col_mask=[0 col_mask(1:end-1)];
%end
%CRC=[CRC fliplr(out)];
CRC=[CRC out];
%%
CRC58_3=reshape(CRC,3,58);
CRC58_3=CRC58_3';
CRCSYM=bi2de(CRC58_3,'left-msb');  
graymap = [ 0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7 ];  
%graymap = [ 0     1     3     2     6     7     5     4 ];
key=[0:7];
for (ii=1:58)
    for (jj=1:8)
    if CRCSYM(ii)==key(jj)
        CRCSYM(ii)=graymap(jj);
        break
    else
    end
    end
end
costas_symbols = [ 3, 1, 4, 0, 6, 5, 2 ];
costas_symbols=costas_symbols';
%%
CHANSYM=[costas_symbols;CRCSYM(1:29);costas_symbols;CRCSYM(30:end);costas_symbols];
%%
%%
sintablen = 7680;
SINTAB = sin(2*pi*(0:sintablen-1)./sintablen);
fs = 48000;
%%
F_required = 1200;
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1200Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(6.25);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1206Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(12.5);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1212Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(18.75);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1218Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(25);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1225Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(31.25);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1231Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(37.5);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1237Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
F_required = 1200+(43.75);
index = 1; step = (F_required/fs)*sintablen;
for i = 1:7680
    sin1243Hz(i) = SINTAB(round(index));
    index = index+step;
    if index>sintablen
        index = index-sintablen;
    end
end
%%
n=length(CHANSYM);
Xcpfsk=[];
for z=1:n
    rep=1;
 rep=rep+1;
    %end
         if(CHANSYM(z)==0)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1200Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
         elseif(CHANSYM(z)==1)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1206Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
         elseif(CHANSYM(z)==2)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1212Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
          elseif(CHANSYM(z)==3)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1218Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
         elseif(CHANSYM(z)==4)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1225Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
         elseif(CHANSYM(z)==5)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1231Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
         elseif(CHANSYM(z)==6)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1237Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
           elseif(CHANSYM(z)==7)
        Xcpfsk=[Xcpfsk,sin1243Hz(1:7680)];
         z=z+1;
    else
        disp('error');
        return
    end
    end
%% Manually execute this command in the command window on at the start of the minute and thereafter every 15 seconds
% to successfully transmit a FT8 message
% sound(Xcpfsk,48000)
```

Comment: If you must post long code blocks as answers then please learn how to format them properly, or ask for help.